# Calculate Probability of getting zero from subtracting set of data in sample space?

Tags: probability

I asked this question before. But It wasn't very clear last time. So now

Let's say I have a any random sample space

2, 5, 4, 9, 3, 7, 15, 12, 6

The only condition is during subtraction the result will always be positive.

(2, 5, 4, 9, 3, 7, 15, 12, 6) -> (3, 4, 9, 3, 7, 15, 12, 6) -> (3, 4, 9, 3, 8, 12, 6)

(3, 4, 9, 3, 8, 12, 6) -> (3, 4, 9, 3, 4, 6) -> (3, 5, 3, 4, 6)

Now element 1 and 3 that is 3 - 3 gone.

we left with

(5, 4, 6) -> (5, 2) -> (3).

(5, 4, 6) -> (4, 1) -> (3). Also valid

(5, 4, 6) -> (1, 6) -> (5).  Also Valid

So we got end result (3). I only care about probability of getting zero.

The sequence of operation on element doesn't matter.

You can take any element from the set at any step and subtract it from any other element from the set.

There will be few sequences we can follow that will result in outcome zero. So If I have a sample space. How do I calculate probability of getting zero at the end for any sample space.

Is there some sort of equation or topic I should look into for this kind of problems?

Even topic suggestion would help a lot.

Comment: I'm inclined to doubt there's any way to do this precisely other than a brute-force enumeration of all possible sequences.  You might try simulation.

Comment: This is even harder than I thought at first, because not all sequences have the same probability.  Usually, the number of elements in the sample space decreases by $1$ at each step, but sometimes it decreases by $2$.  This complicates brute-force calculation of the probability, at least to some extent.

Comment: I am also allowed to create my own sample space with some computer function. But that should give me some control over the probability of getting zero. Can I create such random number of specified sample size, that will allow me to control direction of end result?

Comment: Perhaps you can, but I don't know how.  Is this a school project?  Are you supposed to write a computer program?  If so, you can write a straightforward backtrack program, but be careful about the varying probability of the sequences.

Comment: The most weird problem I faced during this is. if I have three numbers  4, 9, 7. So there two small numbers and one large number. If I do 4-9 = 5 then 5-7 = 2. Also If I do 7-9 = 2 then 2-4 = 2. Same result Right?. But If you interact two small number like 4-7 = 3 then 9-3 = 6. The result changes. This gets more complicated for five and more numbers. Can I somehow at least graph them out to get visual perspective of what I am doing Right Now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127849/discussion-between-niranjan-wagh-and-saulspatz).

Comment: I think the probability of getting $0$ will be very small with more than a handful numbers to start.  I suggest you use simulation to estimate the probabilities.

Comment: how can I do simulation is there any software you can recommend? And How would I put all this in mathematical form.?

Comment: To do simulation, you have to write a program.  Use your favorite language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is an equivalent formulation of the problem that is easier to follow.  An urn contains a number of balls, each labeled with positive integer.  Two balls are drawn at random and their numbers compared.  If the numbers are the same, the balls are simply discarded, otherwise, the balls are replaced by a ball labeled with the difference of the two numbers.  This process is repeated until there are fewer than two balls in the urn.  If the urn is empty at that point, you win, otherwise, you lose.

There is no way to win with the given numbers.  I wrote a python program to do exhaustive search.

```
from itertools import combinations

pop = [2, 5, 4, 9, 3, 7, 15, 12, 6]

def wt(seq):
    n = len(seq)
    if n <= 1:
        return 0
    return 2/(n*(n-1))
    
level = 0
total = 0   # weight of all sequences 
success = 0 # weight of winning sequences
urn = { }
weight = { }
urn[0] = pop
weight[0] = wt(pop)
S = { }
S[0] = list(combinations(urn[0], 2))
while level >= 0 and len(urn[level]) >= 2:
    while S[level]:
        a, b = S[level].pop() 
        u  = urn[level][::]
        u.remove(a)
        u.remove(b)
        if a != b:
            u.append(abs(a-b))
        if len(u) < 2:
            total += weight[level]
        if len(u) == 0:
            success += weight[level]
        level += 1
        urn[level] = u
        weight[level] = weight[level-1]*wt(u)
        S[level] = list(combinations(u, 2))
    level -= 1

# total should be 1, up to roundoff error
print(success, total)
```

This produced the output

```
0 1.0000000005458214
```

Since the total probability computed is $1$ except for some rounding error, I am confident of the result.

This took several minutes to run; I didn't time it unfortunately.

**EDIT**

Here's a simulation script:

```
from random import sample

pop = [2, 5, 4, 9, 3, 7, 15, 12, 6]

trials = 100000
success = 0

for _ in range(trials):
    urn = pop[::]
    while len(urn) >= 2:
        a,b = sample(urn, 2)
        urn.remove(a)
        urn.remove(b)
        if a != b:
            urn.append(abs(a-b))
    success += 1 -len(urn)

print(success, trials)
```

It ran in a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks. It just might work for me.  I was stuck on this issue since a week.

Comment: Just checking. [3, 5, 4, 1, 3, 7, 2, 9, 6] for this set I got 25961 100000. Means probability is 25961/100000 = 0.25961 Right?

Comment: That's an approximation to the probability, but it should be pretty good.  You could use the first script to compute the actual probability.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood it now properly. Its perfect. I almost gave up :)

Comment: @NiranjanWagh Glad to help.

Comment: I made my first game out of your code in Unreal Engine. (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.PythagonStudio.minus)            
Please Ignore the size of the app as Unreal engine makes it very hard to reduce it. Thanks again.